# Bootable ISO vs. Partitioning

Tags: linux, partition, path, iso, bootable

I would like to create a bootable Linux ISO on a USB drive under Debian 9. I found  that the ISO is only bootable if it has been written to the disk `/dev/XdY`. 
If the ISO is written to a specific partition, e.g. /dev/sdd1, then it is not bootable. What is the technical reason behind this?

It works after writing the ISO to a partition and deleting the partition afterwards using Gnome-Disk, this does not delete the file, but makes the disk bootable.

Comment: If you're using BIOS+MBR, what did you get if mark that partition as the only boot-able? I believe standard MS-DOS MBR code will chain boot your boot-able partition.

Comment: I used `sudo dd if=/home/<Windows 10 ISO> of=/dev/sdX` to write the ISO to the USB stick, for some reason, the option Gnome-Disk >> Edit partition >> Bootable is greyed out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- BIOS machines boot disks.
- UEFI machines boot the UEFI partition

So neither of those boot just any partition.

If you're looking to have a bootable ISO booting from a partition, you can add the ISO file to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` and then grub will "boot" the ISO for you.

E.G. for gparted *on my machine* where `/opt` lives in hd2,gpt2

```
menuentry "GParted Live ISO" {
  set ISOFile="/opt/Live-ISOs/gparted-live-0.31.0-1-amd64.iso"
  loopback loop (hd2,gpt2)$ISOFile
  linuxefi (loop)/live/vmlinuz boot=live components config findiso=$ISOFile ip=frommedia toram=filesystem.squashfs union=overlay username=user
  initrdefi (loop)/live/initrd.img
}
```

Comment: nice idea using grub for the ISO.

Comment: May I ask why `linuxefi` and `initrdefi` ? I've only done this without `efi`.

Comment: Because my machine is an UEFI machine and I didn't even try the originals.  [Ping me in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat) if you want me to try @神秘德里克

Comment: 1.) What is the technical reason that deleting a partition actually makes an ISO/drive bootable? 2.) I need to install Windows 10 on my old ThinkPad R60 and copied the ISO onto a USB stick from Debian 9, but it does not seem to be recognized as bootable by the laptop. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @david those would be 2 [new questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).  As you're new here, please don't forget to [accept](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) the answer if it solved your original question.  You can provide a link to this question in your new questions if it would be relevant.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't understand the answer. You can write data either to a "general" drive (/dev/sda) or to a specific partition on it (/dev/sda1). To boot an ISO from a BIOS machine (Windows), it has to be written to the "general" drive. To boot an ISO from a UEFI machine (Linux), it has to be written to a specific UEFI partition on that drive. Problem: 1.) Wrote a Windows 10 ISO to the "general" drive >> Laptop does **not** boot it. 2.) Wrote a Debian 9 ISO to a specific partition >> Need to **delete** the partition, else USB stick is displayed as an external drive, not as a bootable ISO.

Comment: Note: Laptop is a BIOS machine. The ISOs are written onto the USB stick from a Debian 9 desktop machine (UEFI?).

Comment: The reason for my OP: I need to set up my laptop for Windows + Linux dual boot. Neither Windows 10 nor Debian 9 installation is working right now, the former fails already at creating the ISO, latter fails during installation (which is a different topic). Hope this clears it up.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "general drive" under Linux: `/dev/XdA` is a disk... (can be `/dev/hda` for the first disk or `/dev/sda` for the first SCSI disk)  `/dev/sdd2` is the second partition on the 4th SCSI disk.  BIOS machines boot disks, UEFI machines boot EFI partitions only.  If you would have any further questions, do not [hesitate to ask](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) as we won't charge extra!  **;-)**  if the answer now answers your question, [please do not hesitate to accept](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'm aware that /XdY means an entire disk and /XdYN some partition N on disk Y of type X. The problem is that my laptop (= BIOS machine) won't boot the Windows 10 ISO, which I wrote to the USB drive (disk). Also, only **deleting** all partitions from a disk with a Linux ISO on it seem to render it bootable under Debian 9...okay, maybe this question is rather academic, so let's leave it aside.

Comment: If you delete the partition, it becomes a disk *and boots* from a BIOS machine...  **;-)** @david  Windows questions are off-opice here though, but on-topic [at our sister site SuperUser](https://superuser.com)

Comment: That solves the question! Thx